# I am getting the error "Redefinition of 'Schedule::Schedule (){}"

Tags: c++

I get the error:

> Schedule.cc:8:1: error: redefinition
>      of ‘Schedule::Schedule()’
>       8 | Schedule::Schedule (){}
>         | ^~~~~~~~
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

I have researched for hours about header guards and still believe this might be the problem although I have used them (i.m.o in the right way).

Dates.h

```
    #ifndef DATES_INCL
#define DATES_INCL

#include <string>

class Dates {

public:

        char findFormat (std::string input_date);
        bool isLeapYear (int year);
        std::string getDaysPeriod (std::string input_date);
        std::string getYearPeriod (std::string input_date);
        std::string getDaysDash (std::string input_date);
        std::string getYearDash (std::string input_date);
        std::string getMonthDash (std::string input_date);
        void getDatesFileI (char *buffer, std::string filename);
        void getDatesFile (const char *fstring, char *buffer, std::string filename);
        void getDates (const char *fstring, char *buffer);
        std::string collectArgs (char *argv[], int argc);
        std::string getDate(std::string date);

private:
        std::string pname;
};

#endif
```

Event.h

```
    #ifndef EVENT_INCL
#define EVENT_INCL

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Event {

public:
        Event (char cstr[]);
        Event (std::string date);
        Event (const Event&); //Copy Ctor
        Event &operator= (const Event&); //Assignment Operator
        ~Event(); //Dtor
        void set (int year, int month, int day);
        int year () const;
        int month () const;
        int day () const;

private:
        std::string date;
        int eyear, emonth, eday;
};

        std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream&, const Event&);

#endif
```

Schedule.h

```
    #ifndef SCHEDULE_INCL
#define SCHEDULE_INCL

#include "Event.h"
#include "Dates.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Schedule {

public:
        Schedule () = delete;
        Schedule (std::istream &stream);
        Schedule (char cstring[]);
        Schedule (std::string str);
        Schedule (const Schedule&) = default; //Copy Ctor
        Schedule &operator= (const Schedule&); //Assignment Operator
        ~Schedule ();
        void read (std::istream &stream);
        void clear () const;
        size_t size () const;
        bool empty () const;
        Schedule &operator[] (int);

private:
        std::vector<std::string> dates;

};

        std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream&, const Schedule&);

#endif
```

Schedule.cc

```
    #include "Schedule.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "Dates.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Schedule::Schedule (){}

Schedule::Schedule (istream &stream){
        //read from stream
}

Schedule::Schedule (char cstr[]){
        string str(cstr);
        //str is fielname -- .read
}

Schedule::Schedule (string str){
        //str is a filename -- .read from file name
}

Schedule::Schedule (const Schedule &sched){

}

Schedule &Schedule::operator= (const Schedule &sched){

}

Schedule::~Shedule(){}

void Schedule::read (istream &stream){

}

void Schedule::clear (){
        this->dates.clear();
}

size_t Schedule::size (){
        return this->dates.size();
}

bool Schedule::empty (){
        if (this->dates.empty()){
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}

string &Schedule::operator[] (int index){
        return this->dates[index];
}

ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const Schedule &sched){
        //print all events in this schedule     
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the file `Schedule.cc` where the error occurs?

Comment: @churill I made the edit to include Schedule.cc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare the default-constructor as deleted in `Schedule.h`

```
Schedule () = delete;
```

But then have a definition

```
Schedule::Schedule (){}
```

in `Schedule.cc`. Depending on what you want

- don't define the deleted constructor (remove `Schedule::Schedule (){}` from `Schedule.cc`)
- or if you *want* a default constructor don't mark it as deleted and keep the definition in `Schedule.cc`.
- or, since your default constructor doesn't have any custom logic, remove the definition and change the declaration in `Schedule.h` to

  ```
  Schedule() = default;
  ```

  and let the compile generate a default constructor.

The second and third option are identical, just that the third option is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule() is deleted so you can not define it in the code.

```
Schedule() = delete;

// Schedule::Schedule (){} // is deleted and not allowed to be defined
```